# Correctly Placing a QT Splash Screen on 2 screens

Tags: qt, window, splash-screen

My application on startup creates a sort-of "Splash Screen" with quick access buttons to Open, New, etc...  This splash window is placed in the middle of the screen, and the application main window is placed behind it.

Here is the code to do it:

```
void MainWindowButtonDialog::showMe()
{
    setModal(false);
    setWindowFlags(
        #ifdef Q_WS_WIN
            Qt::SplashScreen |
        #endif
            Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

    QDesktopWidget *d = QApplication::desktop();
    QRect t = d->availableGeometry(this);
    move(mapToGlobal(this->geometry().topLeft()).x() + t.center().x() - width() / 2, 
         t.center().y()- height() / 2);
    show();
    raise();
}
```

However I have some problems when the application runs on a two monitor setup. What happens is the following: the Splash screen regardless where the application starts, is created always on the first screen. So if the Window manager decided to open the application on the second screen the splash screen will be far far away on the middle of the first screen... Which is pretty ugly :(

Any idea how can this be fixed?

Comment: "Sort of Splash Screen" - Are you not using the QSplashScreen widget?

Comment: No, just displaying a "Top Level" window, since I also want the applications main window to be accessible while the "Splash Screen" is there and on the first meaningful action from the Main window the Splash disappears.

Comment: Is the window a child of the Main Window, or independent?

Comment: @Merlin069 it's an independent window

Comment: Can you add it as a child?

Comment: @Merlin069 Amazing :) Now it came out exactly where it's supposed to be! Can you formulate an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Ok done and glad we got there in the end ;O)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the splash screen as a child to the MainWindow, it should have its initial coordinates set such that it displays right on top of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling availableGeometry() not with a widget as parameter, but with a screen number. Something like

```
int screen = d->primaryScreen();
QRect t = d->availableGeometry(screen);
```

Comment: Nope, now the popup always pops up on the primary screen, regardless ifthe main window is shown on the second screen.